# Solving for the variance in specified equation

Tags: time-series, matrix

At the moment, I have a task which includes solving for the variance in the following equation (denoted 'sigma' in the expression below, equation 10).

However, given the nature of the equation, I cannot figure out how to solve for sigma.

I'm not sure of the dimensions of the matrices, but I think A, sigma and omega must be square. Usually in matrix equations, we do the inverse; unfortunately, it does not seems to work here!

[image]

Comment: if you take (8) and multiply it by it's transpose and then take the expectation, you'll get (10). Basically, calculate $E(\tilde{X}_{t} \tilde{X}_{t}^{\prime})$ using (8).

Comment: The equation (10) is clearly (by the basic rules of matrix multiplication) a linear function of the components of $\tilde\Sigma,$ as claimed. The assertion following "which shows that..." indicates that whatever kind of object $A$ might be, the limiting value of $A^m$ is zero and the sum of $A^m,$ $m=0,1,2,\ldots,$ is absolutely convergent.  Accordingly, the sum $$\tilde\Sigma=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A^n \tilde\Omega (A^\prime)^n$$must be absolutely convergent as well and by rearrangement you can verify that $A\tilde\Sigma A^\prime + \tilde\Omega=\tilde\Sigma.$